# Is there a phrase "many a weekend"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I just watched a video on youtube and there was a line:

> I spent many a weekend and evening stacking shelves.

I would like to ask is there such a phrase as "many a weekend"? It seems grammatically incorrect.

Below is the link of the video. The line is at about 2:18.

[BBC learning english](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKmsxJkJCqM)

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/many--a

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q="spent+many+a"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This phase is commonly used in contexts similar to the one described above.

Another example would be a phrase such as:

> I have spent **many a** Friday night at a club, dancing.

The phase implies that you have completed an action multiple times under similar or identical circumstances.

Comment: Great answer; even better with a reference.

Comment: Is the fact that I'm English enough of a reference?

Comment: Actually, no. I see that you don't have the [Informed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges) badge, so perhaps you have not taken the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) during your three day membership. Please see this helpful sheet on [how to write a good answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that will not only answer this user's question, but explain why your answer is correct, and possibly help future users with similar questions. And thanks for your participation.